# Query the authenticated user object too often within a http request

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using asp.net core mvc with asp.net identity.

My `ApplicationUser` has a property: `Country` => 'GB' or 'FR' etc...

I want to set the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to the value read from the `applicationUser.Country`. to display all datetime/number values correctly in my views as set by the user.

Thus I created this action filter:

```
 public class LanguageActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        public LanguageActionFilter(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("LanguageActionFilter");
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.HttpContext.User);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(user.Country);

            await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
        }
    }
```

On the action/controller where this actionfilter is set I also run this code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var user = await this.userManager.GetUserAsync(User);      
    var todos = await service.GetTodosAsync(user.Id);
    return View(todos);
}
```

At the moment I call the `this.userManager.GetUserAsync(User);`

TWO TIMES !

Then I thought about passing the user object to the

```
context.HttpContext.Items.Add("applicationUser", user);
```

and grab this user object again within the `Index() action` method:

```
 var user = (ApplicationUser)base.HttpContext.Items["applicationUser"];
```

That worked, but is that a good idea? Do you see any problems with that approach?

Answer (score 1):

What you did is fine...

I'm quoting from the definition of the HttpContext class :

```
/// <summary>
        /// **Gets or sets a key/value collection that can be used to share data within the scope of this request.**
        /// </summary>
        public abstract IDictionary<object, object> Items { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit : It seems ef core doesn't support first level cache. So my idea went for nothing**

Your code works, but i think you won't gain considerable performance.

You probably use aspnet identity with entity framework. Since ef supports [first level cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#3). , if you call `this.userManager.GetUserAsync(User);` more than one, ef retrieves user entity from database only once. As a result two ways approximately have same effect for performance. I wouldn't use `HttpContext.Items` for your case.

Comment: Your link is about EF 4,5,6. Wether the userManager methods from asp.net core identity/EF 7 cache the GetUserAsync can only be found in the source code. Or I enable my sql profiler while running the queries.

Comment: It seems ef core doesn't support first level cache. So my idea went for nothing.